# Create subplots from output (a singular plot) of a function

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a function that returns a singular plot. I would like to repeat this function thrice and have the 3 plots side-by-side in a 1x3 format. How do i go about achieving this?

```
def plot_learning_curve(estimator, X, y, ylim=None, cv=None,
                        n_jobs=-1, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 5)):
    """Generate a simple plot of the test and training learning curve"""
    plt.figure()
    plt.title(str(estimator).split('(')[0]+ " learning curves")
    if ylim is not None:
        plt.ylim(*ylim)
    plt.xlabel("Training examples")
    plt.ylabel("Score")
    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
        estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
    train_scores_mean = np.mean(train_scores, axis=1)
    train_scores_std = np.std(train_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_mean = np.mean(test_scores, axis=1)
    test_scores_std = np.std(test_scores, axis=1)
    plt.grid()

    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, train_scores_mean - train_scores_std,
                     train_scores_mean + train_scores_std, alpha=0.1,
                     color="r")
    plt.fill_between(train_sizes, test_scores_mean - test_scores_std,
                     test_scores_mean + test_scores_std, alpha=0.1, color="g")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, train_scores_mean, 'o-', color="r",
             label="Training score")
    plt.plot(train_sizes, test_scores_mean, 'o-', color="g",
             label="Cross-validation score")

    plt.legend(loc="best")
    return plt
```

I have tried this method, but it just returns an empty 1x3 grid with the plots below this empty grid

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 3, sharex="all", figsize=(15,5), squeeze=False)

axes[0][0] = plot_learning_curve(tuned_clfs_vert_title2[0][0][1],Xs_train1,Y_train1,cv=skfold)
axes[0][1] = plot_learning_curve(tuned_clfs_vert_title2[0][1][1],Xs_train1,Y_train1,cv=skfold)
axes[0][2] = plot_learning_curve(tuned_clfs_vert_title2[0][2][1],Xs_train1,Y_train1,cv=skfold)
```

I'm keen to use this learning curve plotting function as a 'module'. I guess the alternative way is to write a loop within this function.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [matplotlib examples for subplots](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide the axis to the plotting function. I can't use your code, because it is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But here is one approach that you can adapt to your needs:

```
#plot function with defined axis
def plot_subplot(ax, xdata, ydata, plotnr):
    ax.plot(xdata, ydata)
    ax.set_title("Plot {}".format(plotnr))
    return

#subplot grid 2 x 3 to illustrate the example for more than one row/column
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 2, ncols = 3, sharex = "all", figsize = (15,5), squeeze=False)
#reproducibility seed
np.random.seed(54321)
#loop over axes, we have to flatten the array "axes", if "fig" contains more than one row
for i, ax in enumerate(axes.flatten()):
    #generate random length for data
    lenx = np.random.randint(5, 30)
    #generate random data, provide information to subplot function
    plot_subplot(ax, np.arange(lenx), np.random.randint(1, 100, lenx), i)

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]